# RewriteEngine not Rewriting URL locally?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # not a directory
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?params=$1 [L]
```

as you can see, i'm trying to convert anything like

> mysite.com/x/y/z

to

> mysite.com/index.php?params=x/y/z

however, it is not working. i tried mysite.com/home and put a breakpoint on the first line in index.php, but got a 404.

any ideas as to why this isn't working for me? thanks for anything!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that either `mod_rewrite` is not installed, or enabled, or that you have set the `AllowOverride`-directive for the specific directory to `None`. Change it to (at least) `FileInfo`

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabed on your Apache server.

Then remove the comments at the end of the lines:

```
# not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# not a directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

[From the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/configuring.html):

> Lines which begin with the hash
>   character "#" are considered comments,
>   and are ignored. **Comments may not be
>   included on a line after a
>   configuration directive.**